# Navigation to the mentioned URL is not working in android

Tags: android

I used navigation drawer activity and used the below code to load the URL on clicking a menu. On clicking the appropriate menu, it says "loading" but navigation to the mentioned URL doesn't happen. Attached the code below:

MainActivity.java:

```
        else if (id == R.id.nav_1) {

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("type", getString(R.string.settings_label));
            bundle.putString("url", getString(R.string.wp_url));
            fragment = new FragmentWebInteractive();
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_2) {
            // ---------------------------------  Load WebiView with Remote URL -------------------- //
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("type", getString(R.string.remote_type));
            bundle.putString("url", getString(R.string.remote_url));
            fragment = new FragmentWebInteractive();
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_3) {
            // ---------------------------------  Load WebiView with Remote URL -------------------- //
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("type", getString(R.string.interactive_type));
            bundle.putString("url", getString(R.string.interactive_url));
            fragment = new FragmentWebInteractive();
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            tag = "FragmentWebInteractive";

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_4) {
            // ---------------------------------  Load WebiView with Remote URL -------------------- //
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("type", getString(R.string.credits_type));
            bundle.putString("url", getString(R.string.credits_url));
            fragment = new FragmentWebInteractive();
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            tag = "FragmentWebInteractive";

        }
```

Strings.xml:

```
<string name="contacts_label">Courses</string>
    <string name="contacts_type">file</string>
    <string name="contacts_url">contacts.html</string> 

<string name="second_category">Contact Us</string>
    <string name="settings_label">Whatsapp</string>
    <string name="wp_url">whatsapp://chat</string>

    <string name="remote_label">Facebook</string>
    <string name="remote_type">url</string>
    <string name="remote_url">https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=1000195073822</string>

    <string name="interactive_label">Twitter</string>
    <string name="interactive_type">file</string>
    <string name="interactive_url">https://twitter.com/AKcomputersrep1</string>

    <string name="credits_label">Google+</string>
    <string name="credits_type">file</string>
    <string name="credits_url">https://plus.google.com/u/0/112170786242013342091</string>
```

FragmentContacts.java:

```
 webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

        if (getString(R.string.contacts_type).equals("file")) {
            webView.loadUrl("http://akcomputersrepair.in/courses/");
        }  else if (getString(R.string.contacts_type).equals("url")) {
            webView.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=1000195073822");
        }
```

Comment: I don't see the code which should do something with url except passing it to fragment's arguments.

Comment: have you added internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml ??

Comment: What error it is giving

Comment: it doesn't show any error.. It shows loading symbol but no results

Comment: Yes I've given internet permission

Comment: can you please add code of fragment to which you are sending data in arguments ?

Comment: show the code where you load the url. You didn't show it.

Comment: Please view my strings.xml and MainActivity.java file above . URL passing is mentioned there

Comment: No, you didn't get it. Just passing url to a fragment won't load it. You need to call some method like `loadUrl(url)`. You either don't call it, or didn't show it.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko: Please refer the above code.

Comment: still no code that should load the url.

Comment: ok, now I see you don't get the arguments from the bundle. You just ignore them

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace/or add the fragment
Try like this

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("type", getString(R.string.remote_type));
            bundle.putString("url", getString(R.string.remote_url));
            fragment = new FragmentWebInteractive();
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, "FragmentWebInteractive").commit();
```

Another Fragment where you load the url

```
 Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
           String type= bundle.getString("type");
           String url= bundle.getString("url");
        }
 WebView webview =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
if(type.equalIgnorecase(getString(R.string.remote_type)))
        webview.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Have you get the bundle data and loaded in webview?

Comment: Check I have edited my code.Have you done like this?

Comment: getString(R.string.contacts_type).equals("url") what is contacts type?

Comment: please check my strings.xml file

Comment: I think you have put wrong check please check my updated code it should work now

Comment: Thanks, I got the output

Comment: Approve answer if it helped you.!